# How to import lz4 in the Svelte

Tags: svelte, browserify, es6-modules

My Problem is:
I want to use the [lz4 library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lz4) in Svelte without Svelte/kit only in the browser.

I know in the docs that they use the require syntax, but it doesnt work.
Because I can only use the module import/from.
And if I try importing it, like:

- import LZ4 from "lz4/build/lz4";
- import { * as LZ4 } from "lz4/build/lz4";

Nothing worked its allways: `Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default`

Then I saw that all the node.js files get preprocessed by `browserify`.

Thats the command the lib uses:

> browserify  -r ./lib/utils-js.js:./utils -r buffer -r xxhashjs -r ./lib/lz4l.js:lz4 -o build/lz4.js lib/lz4l.js

But as I found out browserify doesnt support import/from so I need to use `babelify`.

Thats now my command to create the script:

> browserify -r ./lib/utils-js.js:./utils -r buffer -r xxhashjs -r ./lib/lz4l.js:lz4 -s lz4 -t babelify -o build/lz4.js

But it still displays the same error when importing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, but I am not satisfied with the solution:

Just like in the docs I add a script at the index.html with a script:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lz4@0.6.5"></script>`

and then just use it in your component like this:

`const LZ4 = require('lz4');`

I thought I need to import it with import/from and if there is any solution to achieve that it would be perfect.
I tried it before with `const LZ4 = require('lz4');` but i thought i need to put the path to the file and not **lz4**.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).